# VariablesSaver.cs is corrupted after project migration in newer Unity version

Tags: unity

I updated Unity Editor version to 2021.3.0f1 from I do not remember which version where I had a project.

After reimporting, almost all is fine, except 2 exceptions in console about syntaxis error in `VariablesSaver.cs`. I opend that file to explore the problem, and found out that the part of file seems to be just erased. That's what it has:

```
using UnityEngine;

namespace Unity.VisualScripting
{
/// <summary>
/// Listens to the OnApplicationQuit on OnApplicationPause
/// hooks to trigger the serialization of saved variables into PlayerPrefs.
/// </summary>
[Singleton(Name = "VisualScripting SavedVariablesSerializer", Automatic = true, Persistent = true)]
[AddComponentMenu("")]
[DisableAnnotation]
[IncludeInSettings(false)]
public class VariablesSaver : MonoBehaviour, ISingleton
{
    private void Awake
```

Does anyone have the full file, or how to fix it?

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling the visual scripting package via the package manager?

Comment: @DMGregory, thanks for the tip. I just deleted it, because I have not ever used it, just after that there was about 200 errors in console, but I just cleared it, and all seems to work. Thanks

Comment: Add your solution as an Answer below.

Answer (score 1):

As @DMGregory pointed, the problem with stuff (packages) like visual scripting can be managed via package manager. In my case I just deleted it at all, and it fixed my problem.

1. On top tabs go to `Window` -> `Package Manager`
2. In top left select `In project`
3. From the packages list that will be loaded choose needed and in bottom right there will be `Remove` button